# google storage file download

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Folks,
  Why would it matter how a publicly accessible object which is stored in a Google Storage Bucket is downloaded?

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png
```

Using tools such as `wget` or `curl`...  seem to be garbling the file.

```
$ wget https://storage.cloud.google.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png

...
$ ls -all -h
56K Feb  2 01:32 test.png
```

Same goes for the trusty:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    fileUrl := "https://storage.cloud.google.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png"

    if err := DownloadFile("test.png", fileUrl); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

// DownloadFile will download a url to a local file. It's efficient because it will
// write as it downloads and not load the whole file into memory.
func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) error {

    // Get the data
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Create the file
    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()

    // Write the body to file
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    return err
}
```

The only way that seems to be reliable is using `gsutil` or browsing to the gcp console.  Thoughts?

Is it possibly because its returning a `302`?

```
curl -I https://storage.cloud.google.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png                                                                                                        ~/Downloads/transforms/tmp
HTTP/2 302
content-type: application/binary
location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cds&passive=1209600&continue=https://storage.cloud.google.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png&followup=https://storage.cloud.google.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png
content-length: 0
date: Sun, 02 Feb 2020 06:33:13 GMT
server: ESF
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
```

How does one grab a reliable link if thats the case?

Comment: You're being redirected when not logged into an account. Your `test.png` file will contain the HTML from the login page. For me it doesn't work with wget or curl either. Maybe after you logged in on your machine (with `gsutil`) it put credentials into the `.netrc` file, which is also used by `curl` and `wget`. You probably need to use one of their libraries to log in and access this storage

Comment: @xarantolus now that makes total sense!   Thank you!   I need to figure out how to make the bucket world readable without any kind of login, just like an S3 object

Comment: I will post an update to my question... found something super interesting which seems dumb as all hell

Answer (score 6):

As folks have kindly mentioned, the contents of the file were html....   After a more careful look, the following is apparent:

Do not use the URL in the box here:
[image: dont use]

But rather right-click on Public :
[image: use]

As you can see, the 2 URLs are slightly different.

https://storage.cloud.google.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png
https://storage.googleapis.com/convertedexcelfiles/test.png

Second one works... I have a strange feeling that others, less technically savvy would have an awful time with this.  At 3am this was infuriating.  I should have simply catted the file... but who would have expected it!  Great job on the UI google... the hell?

Comment: Are you able to download the file with wget?  I have the two urls, but when I use wget I only get a redirect returned.

Comment: Also I noticed I can take off the s to make it an http link if others don't have ssl